# How can I map json fields with object type and array type?

Tags: java

Here is a Response in Json:

```
{

  "info" : {
      "risk" : <object>,
      "operations" : <array>,
      "status" : <string>
  }
}
```

How can I map this in a class?
Here is my class mapping I tried:

```
public class Info {
 
    private Object risk;
    private Array operations;
    private String status;

}
```

Comment: So, how did you perform the mapping itself? I only see a Java class containing properties.

Comment: There is not enough info at all. How do you deserialize JSON? 
Do you use the Jackson library?

Comment: @MaksymRudenko objectmapper

Comment: You only have the top level of fields and subitems. What types of items are in the array? What fields does the risk object have?

Comment: @xdhmoore its unknown, it just stated its an object and the other one is array

Answer (score 1):

Try to use jackson databind https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind with following method:

```
public static Object convertJsonStringToObject(String jsonString, Class classToConvert) {
        try {
            return new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, classToConvert);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            LOG.error("Error when convert object from json.", e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

```
Info info = (Info) JsonConverter.convertJsonStringToObject(stringJson, Info.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class definition should look like below:

```
public class A {
    private Info info;
}
    
public class Info {
    private YourClass risk;
    private List<YourAnotherClass> operations;
    private String status;
}
```

And you can deserialize a json string by using Jackson. Note your target class type should be `A.class`.

If you don't know the content of the json string, you can use `JsonNode` to iterate it.
For example:

```
public static void iterate(JsonNode node) {
    if (node.isValueNode()) {
        System.out.println(node.toString());
        return;
    }
    
    if (node.isObject()) {
        Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> it = node.fields();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Entry<String, JsonNode> entry = it.next();
            iterate(entry.getValue());
        }
    }
    
    if (node.isArray()) {
        Iterator<JsonNode> it = node.iterator();

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            iterate(it.next());
        }
    }
}
    
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String jsonStr = ""; // your input string
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode node = objectMapper.readTree(jsonStr);
        iterate(node);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: But i dont know whats inside the risk. and operations